# how to sort a file according to another file?

Tags: linux, perl, shell

Is there a unix oneliner or some other quick way on linux to sort a file according to a permutation set by the sorting of another file?
i.e.:

**file1:**  (separated by CRLFs, not spaces)

```
2
3
7
4
```

**file2:**

```
a
b
c
d
```

**sorted file1:**

```
2
3
4
7
```

so the result of this one liner should be

**sorted file2:**

```
a
b
d
c
```

Comment: What would be the input for the script ... file1, file2 and sorted_file1? Or should the script do the sorting of file1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
paste file1 file2 | sort | cut -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a perl one-liner that will print the contents of file2 based on the sorted input of file1.

`perl -n -e 'BEGIN{our($x,$t,@a)=(0,1,)}if($t){$a[$.-1]=$_}else{$a[$.-1].=$_ unless($.>$x)};if(eof){$t=0;$x=$.;close ARGV};END{foreach(sort @a){($j,$l)=split(/\n/,$_,2);print qq($l)}}' file1 file2`

**Note:** If the files are different lengths, the output will only print up to the **shortest** file length.

For example, if file-A has 5 lines and file-B has 8 lines then the output will only be 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks to @glenn-jackman for his **very cool** [paste](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste "man paste"), [sort](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/ "man sort") &  [cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut "man cut") answer!